# Static libraries in Qt 5.14 MinGW toolchain? (default Qt installation)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, static-libraries, static-linking

Just now I noted that the MinGW Toolchain that comes with the default Qt installation, at least Qt 5.14, comes with a `lib` directory with `libQt5*.a` files. Are those files static libraries?

I think so because:

1. They have a size similar to the ones that I get when I compile Qt statically for release.
2. `$file ./libQt5Core.a` outputs `./libQt5Core.a: current ar archive`, which is the same that it outputs for the statically compiled ones.

If indeed they're static libraries, ***how can I tell QMake (for example editing the `.pro` file) to link to those instead of linking to the shared ones?***

[image: Windows screenshot of Qt static libs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are those files static libraries?

No. They are not static. Qt’s default online installer provides only shared libraries. That *.a files are so-called import libraries.

Import library is an .a or .lib library, but it only contains bit of information needed to tell the linker/OS how your program interacts with the dll’s.

If you need Qt static windows build for some reasons, you have some options:

- **HARD** Build whole Qt (or needed modules) by [yourself](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW).
- **EASY** Use [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg): `vcpkg install qt5:x64-windows-static`

With vcpkg you can create custom MinGW [triplet](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/triplets/) if you need MinGW for some reason. But I suggest you stick with MSVC.

Comment: Just to be sure about what you said, I installed Qt through the offline installer. The same applies. What you call *bit of information* does not match with the fact that the size of the libraries is more or less the same of the static Qt libraries that I get when building Qt. They're heavy.

Comment: BTW thanks for the tip about **vcpkg**. That may save me lot of work if I can skip the building of Qt, you deserve my upvote for that. Just hope I do not get the random crashes of Qt Quick Controls 2 applications that I get with personal builds of Qt.

Comment: @lateo96 Those binaries are dynamic. The Qt company does not provide static binaries. The size of binaries has nothing to do with runtime/linkage type, Qt just huge. You can try to investigate runtime/linkage type with [DUMPBIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Thanks. Seeing `.a` libraries in Qt toolchains was some confusing to me.